# How to get entities near specific entity in Google App Engine Objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

So lets say I have 100.000 entities of type *Foo*. Foo has a property *bar* that is indexed. Now, for a specific Foo A I want to get 10 Foos closest to A when sorting all Foos by bar.

The thing is, I do not want to do this manually since it will be really slow because of 100k+ entities.

One idea is to use offset and limit like this:

```
ofy().load().type(Foo.class).order("-bar").offset(offset).limit(limit).list();
```

but that requires that I know the position of my Foo A, which I don't.

I had a working solution to this that was a separate entitity that just stores the position of all Foos and updating that table once a minute. It got really slow and caused OutOfMemoryError, so I need something different.

Anyone wanna take a shot at this?

Comment: what do you mean: 'I want to get 10 Foos closest to A'? By which property it should by closest? Bar? Bar is numeric or text?

Comment: 10 Foos closes to A sorted by Bar desc. Bar is numeric. There is no problem with fetching a list of results sorted by Bar.

Comment: Offset wont help because its O(n), it will need to run through the shole 'offset' number of index entries, it can't just jump to that possition.

Comment: Look at geolocation libraries for the datastore, they do something similar to find closest points in 2 dimensions in a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
List<Foo> biger = ofy().load().type(Foo.class).filter("bar >=", A.getBar()).order("bar").limit(10).list();

List<Foo> lower = ofy().load().type(Foo.class).filter("bar <", A.getBar()).order("-bar").limit(10).list();

List<Foo> closest = getClosest(A, biger, lower);
```

Comment: This is a smart solution! Thanks for that. Just a small modification: due to the way query.limit(int) works(it takes the first n), the bigger list needs to change to List<Foo> bigger = ofy().load().type(Foo.class).filter("bar>=", A.getBar()).order("bar").limit(10).list(); Notice the that filtering is done first and order must be done after that AND with reverse order. It may seem unintuitive but I just confirmed it through testing. Change this in your answer and I'll accept it.